# Access to aws-lambda context when running nodejs + expressjs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I'm, just starting out with AWS-Lambda, AWS-API Gateway and ExpressJs. I'm having trouble finding how the AWS-Lambda "context" is available in my "ExpressJs" application.

I'm using:

- AWS-Lambda
- AWS-API Gateway
- NodeJs v4.3.2
- ExpressJs 4.14.1
- ClaudiaJs 2.7.0

In Aws Lambda I use aws-serverless-express to receive the API-Gateway request and initialize the node application. The following is the structure I have found from different tutorials, etc

lambda.js (Initiated from API-Gateway. Supplying the "context" variable in the call to "app.js")

```
'use strict'
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)
exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context)
```

The core of my app.js express is:

```
var express = require('express');
...
var app = express();
...
app.use('/', index);
...
module.exports = app;
```

My questions:

1. Is there a way to access the AWS-Lambda "context" with this
   structure?
2. If not, what would be the best "pattern" to make it available?

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add middleware included in the aws-serverless-express package which exposes the `event` and `context` objects. You add it like this:

```
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())
```

Once this middleware is configured the `event` and `context` objects will be added to the request. You access those objects like so:

```
var event = req.apiGateway.event;
var context = req.apiGateway.context;
```

Comment: Thx, Works fine. A few tips for others though they might be obvious: (1.) "app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())" must be done before any "app.use('/', index);" that will use the API-Gateway context/event (2.) General info available here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of the `@codegenie/serverless-express` package, you can easily access the API Gateway event context in your controllers without any additional middleware.

Nothing to do in handler function.

Simply add to your controller :

```
const { getCurrentInvoke } = require('@codegenie/serverless-express')
...
const currentInvoke = getCurrentInvoke()
const context = currentInvoke.event.requestContext
```

[Source](https://github.com/CodeGenieApp/serverless-express/blob/mainline/UPGRADE.md)

Comment: I looked into the implementation of the getCurrentInvoke and it seems rather buggy to me.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CodeGenieApp/serverless-express/1376bd01e29f6bcf911f86a2b17a5cb85b2844ec/src/current-invoke.js

This doesn't factor in the fact that Lambda will reuse the same instance to serve multiple requests concurrently if you're using Node.js 10.x runtime or later. 

This pattern does not account for concurrent execution within the same Lambda instance, which could lead to incorrect event and context data being accessed across different invocations.

Comment: Very interesting point @MridangAgarwalla ! Do you have any suggestions to avoid this issue, maybe another way to extract context from event directly ?