# Nestjs on AWS Lambda (Serverless Framework) | How to access the event parameter?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nestjs, serverless-framework

I'm hosting a Nestjs application on AWS Lambda (using the Serverless Framework).
Please note that the implementation is behind AWS API Gateway.

**Question:** How can I access to `event` parameter in my Nest `controller`?

This is how I bootstrap the NestJS server:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Server } from 'http';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import * as awsServerlessExpress from 'aws-serverless-express';
import * as express from 'express';

let cachedServer: Server;

const bootstrapServer = async (): Promise<Server> => {
    const expressApp = express();
    const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter);
    app.enableCors();
    await app.init();
    return awsServerlessExpress.createServer(expressApp);
}

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, context) => {
    if (!cachedServer) {
        cachedServer = await bootstrapServer()
    }
    return awsServerlessExpress.proxy(cachedServer, event, context, 'PROMISE')
        .promise;
};
```

Here is a function in one controller:

```
@Get()
getUsers(event) { // <-- HOW TO ACCESS event HERE?? This event is undefined.
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "This function works and returns this JSON as expected."
    }
```

I'm struggling to understand how I can access the `event` paramenter, which is easily accessible in a "normal" node 12.x Lambda function:

```
module.exports.hello = async (event) => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'In a normal Lambda, the event is easily accessible, but in NestJS its (apparently) not.'
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Solution:*

Add AwsExpressServerlessMiddleware to your setup during bootstrap:

```
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())
```

Note: The `app.use` should be *before* `app.init()`

Now the `event` and `context` object can be accessed:

```
var event = req.apiGateway.event;
var context = req.apiGateway.context;
```

Credits: [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436527/access-to-aws-lambda-context-when-running-nodejs-expressjs)

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of the `@codegenie/serverless-express` package, you can easily access the API Gateway event context in your controllers without any additional middleware.

Nothing to do in handler function.

Simply add to your controller :

```
const { getCurrentInvoke } = require('@codegenie/serverless-express')
...
const currentInvoke = getCurrentInvoke()
const context = currentInvoke.event.requestContext
```

[Source](https://github.com/CodeGenieApp/serverless-express/blob/mainline/UPGRADE.md)